# Outbound audio disappears for WebRTC call for users on iPhone 14 iOS 16

Tags: webrtc, web-audio-api

I am facing the issue that outbound audio disappear completely for WebRTC call for a user on iPhone 14 and 14 Pro using the latest iOS - iOS16 with Safari.

This problem appears only on outbound audio. The person using the affected device can hear other people in the call, but others cannot hear that person on iPhone14 iOS16.
Also, as far as I know, this problem occurs when using a Web Audio Api called AudioContext().

Has anyone else discovered the same issue?
Or has found the solution to this?

This must be an issue in the latest iOS ecosystem but I am trying to figure out something to fix this issue or a possible workaround.

Thanks in advance.